# Xcode Bad Access Error when calling method

Tags: xcode

I have a ViewController and in the viewDidLoad Method i initialize a GLKView.
After the GLKView is initialized i try to call a method of that View:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myController = [[MyController alloc] init];
    self.myController.parameter1 = @"BLA";

    [self.myController initTargets];
}
```

My initTargets Method is not really amazing. It actually does not more 
than this:

```
- (void) initTargets
{
    MyTarget *targetOne = [[MyTarget alloc] initWithParameter:self.parameter1];

    [self.targets addObject:targetOne];
}
```

When i try to call the initTargets Method like described above i get the 
following error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0xe80000000)
```

I never had such a Problem with just calling methods and i dont know what 
this error is trying to say me.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: unfortunately no. Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0xe80000000) is everything i get from xcode.

Comment: I doubt anyone can help you then.

Comment: try change `initTargets` to something else? method started with `init` have special meaning especially in ARC code.

Comment: No thats doesnt solve it. btw i have many methods starting with init they are all working except this initTargets.

Comment: if you can show your full code....atleast

Comment: where us allocate self.targets?

Comment: Try enabling [zombie](http://i.imgur.com/xn9H2F4.png) objects from schemas, it may help you to find the problem

Answer (score 1):

Go to Breakpoints pane in xCode, and click the plus sign from the lower left corner. By default, xCode adds an "All exceptions" breakpoint, which means it will stop at any exception, before the actual crash. This is how I debug all "Bad access" exceptions, except for the ones in blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Your accessing an object or pointer that doesn't exist / hasn't been allocated yet.  Or has already been destroyed.

So either MyTarget isn't being allocated properly or self.targets isn't.

What is self.targets ? Does that need to be allocated first ?

Also, you have self.paramter1, shouldnt it be self.myController.parameter1 ?